# Prove that the number $2a+b+c$ is not a prime number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

> Let $a,b,c$ be positive integers such that ${ a }^{ 2 }-bc$ is a perfect square.  prove that the number $2a+b+c$ is not a prime number.

I have no idea about the solution . How can I start to prove it .

Comment: try doing a proof by contradiction.

Comment: Argh! **Don't** type your entire question in math mode with \quad for spaces. Why would you even do that, I don't even my eyes my eyes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us assume that $p=2a+b+c -$ prime. Then $a^2-bc=a^2-b(p-2a-b)=(a+b)^2-pb$. If this number is equal to $n^2$, it is less $a^2$, and $n < a$. It turns out that $pb=(a+b+n)(a+b-n)$, where both factors  exceed  $b$. Therefore, each of them is strictly less than $p$, ie $p$ is not divided. This contradicts the fact that the product is divided into simple $p$.

Comment: What do you mean by "both factors over $b$"?

Comment: This just means "both factors exceed $b$". Great solution!